# Minimum SQL Server rights that allow viewing column default values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL Server 2008 database, some of the fields (columns) in some of the tables are configured with default values.

I have a requirement to limit user security as much as possible, ideally only allow read/write permissions. However, the users need to be able to see what the default values for the columns (well it's actually an application that needs to read the defaults).

Normally I can give the user access to the following roles if I want read/write only:

- `db_datareader`
- `db_datawriter`

The problem is that this prevents access to the default values. This can be confirmed by opening a table is design view (they get a message saying they have limited access and can only view the table design), and the default values are just shown blank.

If I add the `db_owner` role then they can view the default values fine, but I don't want to give the owner powers.

Is there something else I can do in order to restrict to only read/write but with the extra ability to to see what the default values are?

Comment: I think you need ALTER permissions on that table.  Try granting that user ALTER permissions and see if that helps.

Comment: @Kris no, you shouldn't grant `ALTER` to view definitions, unless you also want them to be able to `ALTER`. For just viewing definitions, that's what `VIEW DEFINITION` is for.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake, i misread the question.  I thought they needed to view and change them.  My apologies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will allow the defaults to show up in the lower pane of the table designer:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.tablename TO [username];
```

Of course this doesn't give them the ability to make any *changes* to the table, and in general [I discourage the use of the designers anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers). They're littered with bugs and inconsistencies. With `VIEW DEFINITION` rights, your user can also pull this information from the catalog views:

```
SELECT 
  [constraint] = d.name, 
  [column] = c.name, 
  [default] = d.definition 
FROM sys.default_constraints AS d
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON d.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  AND d.parent_column_id = c.column_id
  WHERE s.name = N'dbo'
    AND t.name = N'tablename';
```

> Is there a way to do something similar for whole tables of database? I mean, about the `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.tablename TO [username];`.

Sure, dynamic SQL is very handy here.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N''GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON ' 
  + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + N' TO [username];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id];

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar for whole tables of database? I mean, about the `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.tablename TO [username];`.

Comment: @Simon See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I thought maybe there was a way to do this for whole tables all at once without executing something on each table one by one like that. But it works for me so I go with this. Big thank to you.

Comment: @Simon Sure, you could grant view definition on the schema (e.g. `dbo`, `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [username];`). However there is no way to restrict that to just the definition of *tables*.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll go with the first way you lead me on. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who may do something similar over a large amoung of table, the PRINT command show a maximum of 8000 chars... It take me about an hour to finally figuring out why it do not take all of my tables!

Comment: @Simon http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Oh, well, you got an answer to everything! Thanks again Aaron. This is pretty usefull!